# Google Sheets: Range not found with recorded macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-macros

I recorded a macro with Google Sheets using absolute references.
One of the steps of the macro is selecting the entire worksheet (to achieve that, I clicked on the upper-left corner of the worksheet.

```
function Boringmacro() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).createFilter();
    spreadsheet.getRange('I1').activate();
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextDoesNotContain('b0')
  .build();
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(9, criteria);
    sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
    spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('F1'));
    spreadsheet.insertSheet(1);
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName('B0 Filter');
    spreadsheet.getRange('\'Sponsored Product Search Term R\'!:').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
...
```

When I replay the macro, I get a 'Range not found error when the script tries to select the entire spreadsheet. I would expect the macro to succeed, since the code is auto-generated by Google Sheets.

The macro fails on the last line of the code snippet.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should replace `'\'Sponsored Product Search Term R\'!:'` with actual range `'\'Sponsored Product Search Term R\'!A:Z'` or something like that